# Can't compile Helloworld.java in cmd

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I installed Jdk 13, added the environment variable as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin` and I installed Eclipse.

I wrote a small `helloworld.java` program as seen below in a new class

```
public class HelloWorldEdit {

    public static void main(String[]  args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

then I tried compiling it with cmd in windows 10 with the following command:

```
javac HelloWorldEdit.java
```

Made sure to place the file in the root repertory of the c drive at this location

```
C:\HelloWorldEdit.java
```

yet it's not working.

Console output is as follows:

```
HelloWorldEdit.java:2: error: error while writing HelloWorldEdit: C:\HelloWorldEdit.class
public class HelloWorldEdit {
       ^
1 error
```

Anyone know what's going on please?

Comment: Your program is missing the class declaration.  That is why you are getting compilation errors.

Comment: You said your file is called `helloworld.java`. Then you said it's called `HelloWorldEdit.java`.

Comment: Now the problem is that the source code filename doesn't match the class name.

Comment: Seriously, you need to slow down ... and write a clear and accurate description of what you are doing.

Comment: The problem is that the Java source file is in `C:\ ` . By default programs don't have write access in this folder, hence you are getting the `error while writing HelloWorldEdit: C:\HelloWorldEdit.class`. Move the Java file into a user directory and then try again.

Comment: Andrea, as @Robert mentioned Windows doesn't allow to write by default into the root of C system partition. Try to write to another path such as C:\projects or another partition.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The class name and file name do match as helloWorldEdit.java forgive my attempt to save keystroked by typing helloWorld.java in the description, the code and file names are correct. I have moved the file to C:\project and ran it again, this time there is no error and no reaction what so ever.

Comment: I set the Path and JAVA_PATH as indicated in your answer aschipfl but to no avail.

Comment: Note that the class file was created, in project repertory, but the display of the Hello World text is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, after running javac i had to run java helloWorldEdit.java to print the text. Thansk for your help guys, the repertory was the issue.